# Abbreviation of qualification

Tags: publications, writing, new-zealand

What is the correct abbreviation for National Certificate in Financial Planning? NatCertFP or maybe NatCertFinPlan?

Answer (score 3):

The two abbreviations you mention yield respectively **2** and **0** results in a Google search. Do not abbreviate that name.